# MySQL count unique values in 2 fields

Tags: php, mysql, count, field

I have a need to count certain values of 2 different fields in a mysql table, preferably with one query if possible.

```
 Number     Answer
 0          Y
 0          N
 1          Y
 2          Y
 0          Y
```

I need to know how many in the field 'Number' have a value of 0.

I also need to know how many in the field 'Answer' have a value of N.

Can you help me construct the query, but also the PHP to get these into a variable for use?

ie

```
 echo "There are ".$number." entries in the number field with a value of 0";
 echo "There are ".$answer." entries in the answer field with a value of N";
```

Thanks for your help, I'm stuck on trying to figure out mysql count before I can even move on to the php.

Comment: [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? SO is not a site for "give me"s or "I need"s. It's made to be informative based on problems users have. We need to see effort to help out.

Comment: haz u sql............

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in a single query using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select 
  sum(case when number=0 then 1 else 0 end) TotalNumber,
  sum(case when answer='N' then 1 else 0 end) TotalAnswer
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/713a42/2)

To fetch these results through PHP, you can use either the `mysqli_` or `PDO` API:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Sum(CASE 
             WHEN number = 0 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           end) TotalNumber, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN answer = 'N' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           end) TotalAnswer 
FROM   yourtable";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo "There are " . $row['TotalNumber'] . "entries in the number field with a value of 0";
    echo "There are " . $row['TotalAnswer'] . "entries in the answer field with a value of N";

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Easier to use `SUM(IF(number=0, 1, 0)) AS TotalNumber`

Comment: @AmazingDreams I am using ANSI standard SQL so it can be used on all databases. :)  But the syntax in MySQL can be abbreviated.

Comment: Interesting, how do I fetch the 2 results?

Comment: @Tom Ask a PHP question, thought it likely will be closed as a duplicate since I can't imagine there aren't a couple dozen "how do I get data into PHP" questions already

Comment: @echo_me sleep what's that? That's why I am running to be a mod...I never sleep

Comment: @echo_me check the election page you can see why I am running -- http://stackoverflow.com/election/

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Select SUM(IF(Number = 0, 1, 0)) as count_numbers,
SUM(IF(Answer = 'N', 1, 0)) as count_answers
From table
```

Saludos ;)

Answer (score -4):

```
Select count(`Number`) from yourtable where `Number` = 0;
Select count(`Answer`) from yourtable where `Answer` = 'N';
```

Comment: Riddle me this, riddle me that, where does the count come from?